# CSS Code for input-textfield

Tags: html, css, forms

Is it possible to create a textfield like this with just pure CSS?

[image: http://cl.ly/3H0v3I2T3u1R082P1O1n]

I'm at this point (SASS Code):

```
input[type="text"]  
  :background  url(../../img/input_text_bg.png) repeat-x
  :border-color light-grey
  :width 210px
  :height 30px
  :-moz-border-radius 4px
  :-webkit-border-radius 4px
  :margin-top 20px
  :margin-left 40px
  :color $dark-grey
```

as you can see i still use a background-image, is it to replace it with some gradient?

Comment: yes you can do this, but you will have some restrictions on browser compatibility.. this is done with CSS3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this CSS for gradient background.

```
background-image: linear-gradient(top, rgb(240,240,240) 10%, rgb(255,255,255) 58%);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgb(240,240,240) 10%, rgb(255,255,255) 58%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgb(240,240,240) 10%, rgb(255,255,255) 58%);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgb(240,240,240) 10%, rgb(255,255,255) 58%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgb(240,240,240) 10%, rgb(255,255,255) 58%);

background-image: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    right top,
    right bottom,
    color-stop(0.1, rgb(240,240,240)),
    color-stop(0.58, rgb(255,255,255))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try Webkits it will allow you to round the border radius and create gradients from a range of colors using basic CSS/CSS3.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS3's box-shadow, and inset. e.g

```
input[type=text] {
    box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 2px 2px black;
}
```